# How to select a location with a button? (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a button in which its function is for the selecting a location. Once a user click that button, he can select the location he wants. How will I do that in android?

Thank you! I hope you could help me!

Comment: didn't understand your question can you explain it in detail??

Comment: I would like to have a way for a user to select a location on a map on a button push. The button would open a Google Maps intent which the user can search and select the location and be back on the main activity. How wil i do it?

Comment: try google place picker api. have a look at this link :
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PlacePicker of the Google Places API : https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker